# How do I create dataframe of one dataframe with added rows from another dataframe that are not present by index in the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say that I have the following dataframes:

```
base_df = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['dog', 'cat'], 'noise':['bark', 'meow']}, index=[1,2])
new_info_df = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['wolf', 'sheep'], 'noise':['woof', 'baa']}, index=[1,3])
```

I want to create a new dataframe with the columns 'animal' and 'noise' that has all the data from base_df and rows from new_info_df where the index of the row isn't already present in the base_df, i.e., the updated dataframe should be equivalent to this:

```
updated_df = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['dog', 'cat', 'sheep'], 'noise':['bark', 'meow', 'baa']}, index=[1,2,3])
```

I have tried

```
pd.concat([base_df, new_info_df], join='outer', axis=1)
```

but I ended up with the columns 'animal' and 'noise' being duplicated which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try boolean indexing + `.concat`:

```py
df = pd.concat([base_df, new_info_df[~new_info_df.index.isin(base_df.index)]])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  animal noise
1    dog  bark
2    cat  meow
3  sheep   baa
```